# NHibernate using 2 schema's within the same application?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Imagine you are writing a large scale application using NHibernate and you want to have 2 seperate schema's (using Sql Server by the way)

1. Application_System (all the tables relating to the system, config tables, user tables etc)
2. Application_Data (all the actual data that is stored/retrieved when the user interacts with the system)

Now I've been trying to find a simple clean way to do this in NHibernate and thought I'd found a solution by using the Catalog and Schema properties so for example:

```
Catalog("Application_System");
Schema("dbo");
Table("SystemSettings")
```

would generate sql for `Application_System.dbo.SystemSettings`. And this kinda works but if I have 2 Catalogs defined then the Create/Delete tables functionality of hbm2ddl.auto stops working. Now I've come to the conclusion that I am probably abusing the Catalog and Schema properties for something it wasn't intended for. However I can't seem to find a simple way of achieving the same thing that doesn't involve some convoluted scaffolding.

Any help would be appreciated. I can't believe NHibernate wouldn't support this out of the box I mean it's a fairly basic requirement.

Answer (score 0):

SchemaExport does not support creating schema/catalog ootb but you can add the create schema/catalog ddl by yourself using auxiliary objects in xml, FluentNHibernate or MappingByCode. Note that the auxiliary object has to be added first.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I kind of found a half way house that I'm reasonably satisfied with. The ISession has a Connection property that exposes a `ChangeDatabase(string databaseName)` method that allowes you to change the database the session is pointing to.

My schema export is still knackered because ultimately it doesn't know which object is for which database so will attempt to save it all to the database defined in the configuration.

You win some you lose some.